# Quick quick question on matrix solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Could someone explain number 2 of the solution:

[image]

Why does the value of b matter? One and three make sense, but I don't understand why the value of b matters in this when we are talking about solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case 2 they say that $a+1 = 0$.  If $a+1 =0 $ then the bottom row of the matrix becomes this:
$$  0 \quad 0 \quad 0 \quad | \quad b $$

This row, in terms of the variables in the system, says $0x + 0y + 0z = b$.  The left-hand side simplifies to just $0$, so the third row in the matrix says $0 = b$.  Therefore the **only** way the system will have solutions in this case is if $b = 0$.  (Note that the case where $b \ne 0$, i.e., a contradiction, is covered in case 1.)  And if $b = 0$ then you really only have two linear equations (from the first two rows in your matrix) that restrict what your three variables can be, since the third equation just becomes $0=0$, which is always true no matter what $x,y,z$ are.  And two linear equations for three variables means you have a free variable, i.e., infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the cases when $b$ does and does not equal zero. In the first case, we would have $0z=0$ which makes since. That is why 2 is true. If $b\neq 0$, however, we have $0z=b\neq 0$, so there are no solutions. That is why the value of $b$ matters.

Answer (score 0):

Note that a system of linear equations has no solution if you have that 
$$0x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = b,$$ where $b \neq 0$. This would correspond to a zerorow in the coefficientmatrix, whereas the same row in the augmented matrix is not a zerorow. Hence the rank of the coefficient matrix would be strictly smaller than the rank of the augmented matrix.

If you would find that a zerorow in the coefficientmatrix corresponds to a zerorow in the augmented matrix, then this means that one at least one variable can take infinitely many values (without a restriction). This corresponds with a complete zerorow in the augmented matrix.

This is why you have to consider the value of $b$ in the solution.